# What are the relevant proposed SE sites on Area 51?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

[Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) is a part of the Stack Exchange network where new SE sites are born.
A site has to go through several stages before being launched, and having an active community is an important ingredient in any successful launch.

Some of the proposed sites are certainly interesting to many users here.
**What are the relevant proposed SE sites on Area 51?**
Please post only one site per answer and briefly justify its relevance to our community.

(The purpose of this question is to collect all relevant Area 51 proposals in one place, so they don't clutter our meta and are easy to find. Special promotion procedures are possible to make this thread more visible when needed.)

Comment: Could you please add how you defined "relevant"? Does it refer specifically to Romance languages or is it broader? For what it's worth, Language Learning SE maintains a [List of language-related Stack Exchange sites](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/438/800).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I specifically wanted to leave "relevant" undefined, so that anyone is free to judge as they will. Anything that is potentially of interest to this community, like history, archaeology, Semitic languages, Romance languages, the Bible, culture, and Greek. I think it's best to leave it open but to request that any poster explains the relevance.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Catalan Language SE proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121280/catalan-language?referrer=JnP6FPU7uLnQ2pViQ8jACw2):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Catalan Language]

It was proposed on February 5, 2019, and may be of interest for the Latin.SE community. The Catalan/Valencian language belongs to the [Occitano-Romance languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occitano-Romance_languages) and has around 10 million speakers among different countries, so it has evolved in quite different ways throughout the years.